# PHP find data within symbols

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am writing a program in PHP, and i need to find data that is in between two sets of symbols, and convert that to a string. For example

```
$main = "Hello, everyone, my name is (-Jack-)"
$string = regex_function('(-', $main) #should return "Jack"
```

How do i get that output, using a regex function or something

Comment: Checked [any of these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$main  = 'Hello, everyone, my name is (-Jack-)';

preg_match_all('/\(\-(?P<name>.*)\-\)/', $main, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);

echo $matches['name'][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is known as [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$main = "Hello, everyone, my name is (-Jack-)";
preg_match_all('/\(\-(?P<name>\w+)\-\)/', $main, $string);
print_r( $string );
```

A sample output on [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3cbwz9).

---

Referring to [@Prasanth's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288740/php-find-data-within-symbols/15288821?noredirect=1#comment21573949_15288821); here's a better regex.

```
$main = "Hello, everyone, my name is (-Jack stuff-) some more text (-John stuff-)";
preg_match_all('/\(\-(?P<name>[\s\w]+)\-\)/', $main, $string);
print_r( $string );
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7JGOx2) link.

Comment: But what if the text is `(-Jack Jack-)` it will not match the pattern